# Is it possible to send control data indoors?

Tags: dji-sdk

When flight testing in the room, the flight controller's GPS is lost and it automatically switches to A mode. At this time, data can not be sent using "sendVirtualStickFlightControlData" method. The connection with the transmitter has not expired.
Although data transmission outdoors was successful, I do not know the reason why indoor communication does not go well.

Data can only be sent when the aircraft status indicator is flashing green light slowly.

Is there a relationship with GPS when doing data communication?

The drone you are using is "Phantom 3 standard".
MobileSDK

Answer (score 1):

Virtual stick definitely works indoors.
It seems that the main culprit is wireless interferences.

For a P3 standard, you are looking at wifi interferences.
It's a real issue when working in indoor dev environment.

You can check if there is a lot of wifi network with any wifi diagnostic application like this app on Android: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.farproc.wifi.analyzer&hl=en

Now for solution, the best of best is a conductive setup, but it's really not trivial to do and will void your warranty.

Non-intrusive solution would be controlling the bands (keeping your wifi at 5Ghz, leave 2.4 free for the P3). This could help but doesn't guarantee to solve it all.

I hope this helps.